# I am trying to create a download button that downloads the images on that pages...with one catch

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to download the images, on a webpage, this is fairly simple. However, the images don't end with jpg/png they are base64 strings. I will post a example of the base64 and function I am trying to code to make this button download..any help would be appreciated...

```html
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

```js
function downloadPhotos() {
 // This code is part of my code for another project (Justin Baskaran)
   var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
   var srcList = [];
   var i = 0;

 setInterval(function(){
 if(3 > i){
     srcList.push(images[i].src);
     var link = document.createElement("a");
     link.id=i;
     link.download = images[i].src;
     link.href = images[i].src;
     console.log("hi")
     link.click();
     i++;
 }
 },1500);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that, if it works, I will erase this question.

Comment: I believe [not erasing it is recommended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate).

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Can you [create a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the problem?

Comment: It is hard, because it uses MQTT, and i cant replicate that

Comment: All I can say, is ask if there is any way to download byte64 image values?

Comment: The method in the other post [seems to work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/d43z2q76/).

Comment: Yes thank you it works! you are a savior!